# Does having multiple ProximityAlerts (or Geofences) set drain more battery than just having one set?

Tags: android, android-location, geofencing, android-geofence

Does each additional ProximityAlert or Geofence locations increase the battery drain of an Android App?
Would there be a significant difference between an app monitoring one location vs five locations vs one hundred locations?
Would there be a difference if all these locations are in one city or if they are spread around the world?
Do these characteristics differ between ProximityAlerts and Geofences?